# Why the output of below program is 1 not 2?

Tags: java, string

Since s3 is created in Heap and s1 and s2 are created in String Constant Pool,s3 and s2 should be treated as different keys and output should be 2.

But output comes out to be 1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String s1 = "vivek";
    String s2 = "vivek";
    String s3 = new String("vivek");

    map.put(s1, "vivek");
    map.put(s2, "vivek");
    map.put(s3, "vivek");

    System.out.println(map.size());

}
```

Comment: `HashMap` uses `equals` to compare objects. And `"vivek".equals(new String("vivek"))` is `true`. Therefore, they are treated as the same key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HashMap class specifies the following on the put operation:

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value
>   is replaced.

So you have replaced with each put operation the old value and only have one item in the HashMap.

see also the associated [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,V))

The question is why the put method assumes the key is the same for s1, s2 and s3. 
The HashCode for String is implemented by performing calculations of the underlying character storage (value). The characters in your variables s1, s2 and s3 are exactly the same, so they will result in the same HashCode.

From the openjdk implementation of [StringUTF16](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/StringUTF16.java) (value is the character storage):

```
public static int hashCode(byte[] value) {
    int h = 0;
    int length = value.length >> 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        h = 31 * h + getChar(value, i);
    }
    return h;
}
```

The HashMap also uses equals, to compare keys. This works because of the implicit contract between the equals and hashCode method. It states that:

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

So the HashMap can safely assume that the HashCode for 2 Objects will be the same, if the comparision with equals returns true for them.

see in the [javadoc of the hashCode Method for Object](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()).

Comment: It is not only hashCodes that are the same, but also `equals` will return true.

Comment: Good point, I have added it to the explanation. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

The HashMap isn't using the memory addresses so it isn't relevant. It's using .equals() between the strings so you assigning to the same key everytime. Therefore you only have 1 key that has a value.

Comment: it uses not only `equals` but also `hashCode` to determine if keys are the same.

Comment: @michalk in the case of a String object though, as far as I'm aware java will dereference and use the string's value. Just like if you were to do System.out.println(String) , it will print the string and not the memory address of the String.

Comment: @michalk It uses `hashCode()` to determine if they are *different.*

Comment: @PreciseMotion Not correct. Try `IdentityHashmap` and see. `println()` doesn't print out the memory address of anything: it prints the result of `String.valueOf()`, which for objects returns the result of `toString()`. In this case it is the `HashMap` and `String.equals()` that are providing the special treatment, not Java in general.